# run onedit on active sheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have looked for an answer for this question, but I am exceptionally green to even rudimentary scripting so I have not been able to understand what I have found.

I have a spreadsheet we are using for a worklist - it is separated into three tabs: Samples / Images / Archive

Users access the spreadsheet to collect items to work - once it is complete they mark Column A as "Complete", and I have code very helpfully provided by ScampMichael to automatically move the row to the "Archive" sheet once they do so:

```
function onEdit(event) {
// assumes source data in sheet named Samples
// target sheet of move to named Archive
// test column with Completed is col 1 or A
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "Samples" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == "Complete") {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
 }
}
```

My challenge is that I can not get this code to work simultaneously for both the "Samples" and the "Images" tab. I gather that this is because you can not have more than one onEdit function per spreadsheet, but so far my efforts to expand the code to look at both tabs has failed.

Any help that can be provided is extremely appreciated!

Comment: You can create another function that processes the Images sheet and call it from the onEdit function. It is unclear what you need to do with the Images sheet.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion - I need to do the exact same thing with the Images sheet. I have tried duplicating this code both in the same script and in a separate file, but I can not get the function to work on both sheets.

Answer (score 0):

It is still not exactly clear what you want to do, but I took a shot at it. I assumed the image is on the same row number as the completed row on samples and when copying the image to archive I append it to the end of the row created in the archive. I made some changes to your code. They are noted. If you need it, I can share my testing spreadsheet.

```
function onEdit(event) {
// assumes source data in sheet named Samples
// target sheet of move to named Archive
// test column with Completed is col 1 or A
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
if(s.getName() == "Samples" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == 
"Complete") {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);//changed to delete the row
 image(row,numColumns)//call function to process Images send row and last column
}}
function image(row,numColumns){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1=ss.getSheetByName("Images")//get Images sheet
  var lc=s1.getLastColumn()
  var data=s1.getRange(row, 1, 1,lc)//get row
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() , numColumns+1,1,1);//add image one column after Samples data on same row.
  s1.getRange(row, 1, 1, lc).moveTo(target);
  s1.deleteRow(row)//delete the copied image row.
}
```